# Using SFINAE to select friend or base class c++x03

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, c++03

Hi I was trying to use SFINAE to check if a variable exists on a class and use it to define which friend should I use, and I found out that when I check the value from has_helloworld it fails to deduct the actual value. Is that expected?
How could I implement something similar?
The output result like this should be:

```
0
1
```

But when I put the friend again it will be

```
1
1
```

I am using c++03 on gcc.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
class has_helloworld
{
    template <typename C> static char (&f( __typeof__(&C::helloworld) ) )[1] ;
    template <typename C> static char (&f(...))[2];
public:
    static const bool value = sizeof(f<T>(0)) == 2 ;
};
template <class T, const bool>
class FriendOption{public: void t (){std::cout<< "genericFriend";  }};
template <class T>
class FriendOption<T, false> {public: void t (){std::cout<< "false friend";  }};
template <typename T>
class Hello 
{
        typedef T field_type;
static const bool test = has_helloworld<field_type>::value;
    //friend class FriendOption<field_type, test >;
public:
    int helloworld() { return 0; }
};
class OTF {
public:
    int helloworld() { return 0; }
};
class test : public Hello <test>
{};

struct Generic {};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << has_helloworld<test>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << has_helloworld<Generic>::value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in the friend but in the test

```
static const bool test = has_helloworld<field_type>::value
```

Pass the whole new type `Hello<field_type>` to the test:

```
static const bool test = has_helloworld<Hello<field_type>>::value;
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ca6f77c730e19c4)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you, you are right, that solve my issue and keeps the right values on the static variable